# Trigger a script at the end of .Appx package installation [UWP]

Tags: windows, uwp, store, nsis, appx

I have a .Appx package made out of a setup I made using NSIS. I want to know if there is a way I can trigger installation of shortcuts of executable(s) of my package at developer-defined places. We can do it in an NSIS package by writing a .nsi script. Is there something similar for .Appx packages?

Answer (score 0):

We can't interfere with the UWP app installation process, but you can modify the app to request the user to be fixed in the start menu when the app first starts.

If you want to know this, please read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/primary-tile-apis).

Best regards.